# Regex match for split

Tags: php, regex, parsing, split

```
fontSize=16.0, fontFamily=sans, align=0, color=FF0000, text="foo, bar"
```

and I need match for spit. Output will be

```
array(
  'fontSize'=>'16.0',
  'fontFamily'=>'sans',
  'align'=>'0',
  'color'=>'FF0000',
  'text'=>'foo, bar'
);
```

I tried next, but it was bad:

```
preg_spit("~[\s]="?[\s]"?,~", $string);
```

Comment: `preg_spit("~[\s]=\"?[\s]\"?,~", $string);`

Comment: you can't split by `,`, because , is in `"foo, bar"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split your input string according to the below regex,

```
,\s(?![^=]*")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/27)

```
<?php
$str = 'fontSize=16.0, fontFamily=sans, align=0, color=FF0000, text="foo, bar"';
$regex = '~,\s(?![^=]*")~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $str);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => fontSize=16.0
    [1] => fontFamily=sans
    [2] => align=0
    [3] => color=FF0000
    [4] => text="foo, bar"
)
```

**Regular Expression:**

```
,                        ','
\s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
(?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
  [^=]*                    any character except: '=' (0 or more
                           times)
  "                        '"'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Split by this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xN4qL9/1